Can't attach VSCode debugger to python application with debugpy
I'm trying to debug remotely Authentik Python files (for example this file ) in a Docker container through port 6800 but whenever I start debugging in VSCode the debug session terminated right after that and leave nothing though breakpoint is set.
The extensions are fine and the Extension Host log shows:
2024-10-11 03:14:51.952 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension charliermarsh.ruff, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onLanguage:python'
2024-10-11 03:14:52.120 [info] ExtensionService#\_doActivateExtension ms-python.black-formatter, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onLanguage:python'
2024-10-11 03:14:52.251 [info] ExtensionService#\_doActivateExtension ms-python.debugpy, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onLanguage:python' 
2024-10-11 03:14:52.342 [info] ExtensionService#\_doActivateExtension ms-python.vscode-pylance, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onLanguage:python'
2024-10-11 03:14:59.573 [info] ExtensionService#\_doActivateExtension vscode.debug-server-ready, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onDebugResolve'
2024-10-11 03:15:21.537 [warning] vscode.json-language-features - Code actions of kind 'quickfix' requested but returned code action is of kind 'source.sort.json'. Code action will be dropped. Please check 'CodeActionContext.only' to only return requested code actions. 
2024-10-11 03:15:23.888 [warning] vscode.json-language-features - Code actions of kind 'quickfix' request

and here is the debugpy log:
0 Starting Session:
{
    "name": "Python: PDB attach Server",
    "type": "debugpy",
    "request": "attach",
    "connect": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 6800
    },
    "justMyCode": true,
    "django": true,
    "logToFile": true,
    "__configurationTarget": 6,
    "clientOS": "unix",
    "debugOptions": [
        "Django",
        "RedirectOutput",
        "ShowReturnValue"
    ],
    "showReturnValue": true,
    "workspaceFolder": "/home/truongnm/Desktop"
}
6 Error:
{}
12 Client --> Adapter:
{
    "command": "initialize",
    "arguments": {
        "clientID": "vscode",
        "clientName": "Visual Studio Code",
        "adapterID": "debugpy",
        "pathFormat": "path",
        "linesStartAt1": true,
        "columnsStartAt1": true,
        "supportsVariableType": true,
        "supportsVariablePaging": true,
        "supportsRunInTerminalRequest": true,
        "locale": "en",
        "supportsProgressReporting": true,
        "supportsInvalidatedEvent": true,
        "supportsMemoryReferences": true,
        "supportsArgsCanBeInterpretedByShell": true,
        "supportsMemoryEvent": true,
        "supportsStartDebuggingRequest": true,
        "supportsANSIStyling": true
    },
    "type": "request",
    "seq": 1
}
21 Client --> Adapter:
{
    "command": "disconnect",
    "arguments": {
        "restart": false
    },
    "type": "request",
    "seq": 2
}
723 Stopping Session

My launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: PDB attach Server",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 6800
            },
            "justMyCode": true,
            "django": true,
            "logToFile":true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: PDB attach Worker",
            "type": "debupy",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 6900
            },
            "justMyCode": true,
            "django": true,
            "logToFile":true

        }
    ]
}

The port 6800 is opened and on LISTEN mode. I don't know what could be causing the debugger to disconnect immediately after trying to attach, and how can I fix this issue to successfully debug my Python application with debugpy?

You could try to narrow the scope for this issue by trying to reproduce the issue with debugpy alone.Could you try to launch a debugpy session in terminal and check if it will be terminated unexpectedly?Also a full steps for reproduction would be helpful.
